# Concat In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason the keyText variable isn't showing any value when it should concat for each variable in keywords.

When someone clicks the button it runs addKeyword and grabs the value of the input.

Tried to Console.Log the keyText variable and didn't work at all.

```
var keywords = [];
      var keyText = "";

      function addKeyword() {
          var keywordName = document.getElementById("keywordAdd").value
          keywords.push(keywordName);

          keywords.forEach(showKeywords);

          function showKeywords(item, index) {
              var newString = "<span class='keyword' onclick='delKeyword(" + index + ")'>✖ " + item + "</span>";
              keyText.concat(newString);
              document.getElementById("keywords").innerHTML = keyText;
          }

      }
```

No Errors shown in Console. Expected result is a list of  but doesn't show.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) doesn't mutate the string, it returns a new string.
You need to do something like this:

```
keyText = keyText.concat(newString);
```

By the way, your current approach is not that efficient because it changes the element's inner HTML at each iteration. You should probably do that only once after the HTML for all the elements is generated. Here is another approach that does that:

```
const result = keywords.map((item, index) => (`<span class="keyword" onclick="delKeyword(${index})">✖ ${item}</span>`)).join('');
document.getElementById("keywords").innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Perfect solved it. However now whenever I click the button it relists current keywords saved to the array all over again rather than just adding a singular one.

Comment: @Policeboy109 You can reset (`keyText = ""`) the variable that you're using, you can do that after the `keywords.forEach(showKeywords);` call.

Answer (score 0):

Titus answer is correct, but you can simply use :

```
keyText += newString;
```